# JSON file specific keywork via powershell

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

I want to get lines which are `serviceArea` equal `Skype` like below.

```
 {
    "id": 127,
    "serviceArea": "Skype",
    "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
    "urls": [
      "*.skype.com"
    ],
    "tcpPorts": "80,443",
    "expressRoute": false,
    "category": "Default",
    "required": true
  },
  {
    "id": 128,
    "serviceArea": "Common",
    "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Microsoft 365 Common and Office Online",
    "urls": [
      "*.config.office.net",
      "*.manage.microsoft.com"
    ],
    "tcpPorts": "443",
    "expressRoute": false,
    "category": "Default",
    "required": true
  },
  {
    "id": 130,
    "serviceArea": "Common",
    "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Microsoft 365 Common and Office Online",
    "urls": [
      "lpcres.delve.office.com"
    ],
    "tcpPorts": "443",
    "expressRoute": false,
    "category": "Default",
    "required": true
  },
  {
    "id": 146,
    "serviceArea": "Skype",
    "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
    "urls": [
      "statics.teams.microsoft.com"
    ],
    "tcpPorts": "443",
    "expressRoute": false,
    "category": "Default",
    "required": true
  }
```

My desired output :

```
*.skype.com
statics.teams.microsoft.com
```

Comment: As you probably know StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You can start by reading the data and using ```ConvertFrom-Json```.

Comment: this is NOT valid JSON. You will need to encase the `{stuff},{stuff}` like `[{stuff},{stuff}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is wrapped in an array (as mentioned in comments above), you could do something like this to filter the data.

```bsh
param(
    $jsonFile = "$PSScriptRoot\data.json",
    $likeFilter = "*Skype*"
)

$convertedObjects = Get-Content -Path $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json 
    
$result = $convertedObjects | Where-Object { $_.serviceArea -like $likeFilter } 

$result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid due to is has no `root` element. As I see, it is array (list)

```
$text = @'
[
<your text here>
]
'@
```

---

After that, you can select `urls`

```
$result = $text | 
    ConvertFrom-Json  | 
    Where-Object { $_.serviceArea -eq 'Skype' } |
    ForEach-Object { return $_.urls }
```

Comment: Isn't this missing backticks?